# How to know a delete operation occurred in EditText in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I want to get a callback when a character is deleted in an EditText.

How can I do It?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no CallBack for  Removing charactor directly !!

But each time you add any text or edit your EditText text all of **TextWatcher** CallBacks called **Respectively**

(1-**beforeTextChanged** , 2-**onTextChanged**, 3-**afterTextChanged**)

Therefore you can check delete operation in all of them as below.
Notice that you **don't need to check** delete operation in all callbacks . 
There are 3 ways to understand delete operation in TextWatcher in **3 TextWatcher** **CallBacks** and each of them can solve your problem  :)

.I think it is  better for you to know about some of TextWatcher callBacks arguments.

As @**ikerfah** said

- **start** is the start index that is about to be deleted
- **count** is the length of the text that is about to be deleted
- **after** is the length of the text that is about to be added

**Ways :**

1. **beforeTextChanged**:  you **compare** after argument with count argument .
2. **onTextChanged**: you **declare a field** in your activity or fragment and fill the field each time `onTextChanged` called . compare your
   field which is **previous EditText count** with **count** argument which is
   current EditTextCount;
3. **afterTextChanged:** It is pretty like `onTextChanged`  listener but just you use **length** instead of count.

> Change Your Final **addTextChangedListener** link below:

```
    yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int count, int after) {

        if (after < count) {
            // delete character action have done
            // do what ever you want
            Log.d("MainActivityTag", "Character deleted");
           }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {

      //mPreviousCount count is fied
         if (mPreviousCount > count) {
                // delete character action have done
                // do what ever you want
                Log.d("MainActivityTag", "Character deleted");
            }
            mPreviousCount=count;
        }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        Log.d("MainActivityTag",editable.toString());
        int length=editable.length();

      //mPreviousLength is a field
        if (mPreviousLength>length)
        {
            // delete character action have done
            // do what ever you want
            Log.d("MainActivityTag", "Character deleted");
        }
        mPreviousLength=length;
    }
 });
```

Comment: This solution is not a good solution. You can end up with less number of characters even without a delete operation. For example, when you type, the keyboard gives you suggestions, and those suggestions might be smaller in length than the current text. So your solution will wrongly mark suggestions as delete case.

Answer (score 5):

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

new inside your beforeTextChanged callback you have three parameters

- start is the start index that is about to be deleted
- count is the length of the text that is about to be deleted
- after is the length of the text that is about to be added

now you need only to compare between those parameters to achieve anything you desire with the callback beforeTextChanged